# Select component from Angular Material don't load Option components in Karma

Tags: angular, karma-runner, angular-material

I'm having troubles with Angular 4, Angular Material and Karma. I have a page with a single instance of an Angular Material Select component with 3 fixed Option components (took from the official documentation).

I've created a new app with Angular CLI. When I run the app it works great, but when I'm trying to write tests with Karma and Testbed the Option components are not present. The same if I try to click myself on the Select component in Karma browser, at the bottom of the page.

Here is a screenshot of what is happening :

[image]

Because it's not possible to reproduce it on plunker or codepen, i've made a zip file with an empty project that reproduces the problem : http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=35616718992258616489

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I'm running into the same problem. I haven't found a real solution, but I have a workaround.

Instead of doing a `fixture.query(By.css('md-option'))`, which returns `null`, I check the `options` property of the `MdSelect` component:

```
this.selectElement = this.fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('md-select');
this.optionElement = this.selectEl.componentInstance.options.first;
...
expect(this.optionElement.value).toEqual(this.expectedOptionElementValue);
```

[Open issue](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/5082) on the topic for those interested.